# How to draw line on Map View given coordinates?

Tags: android, android-mapview

How to draw line on `MapView` given coordinates?

AFAIK, on iPhone it is possible.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a more complete answer to your question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To use a [MapView](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html?com/google/android/maps/MapView.html) your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) must extend [MapActivity](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html?com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html).

For each line you want to draw (or really anything else) you need to subclass [Overlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html?com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) and do the drawing in the `Overlay`'s `onDraw()` method. Once you've created your `Overlay` add it to the `MapView` with something like `mMapView.getOverlays().add(new MyOverlay());`.

Inside your custom `Overlay` you'll want to get a [Projection](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html?com/google/android/maps/Projection.html) with something like `Projection p = mapView.getProjection();`. From the `Projection` you can convert GPS coordinates into screen coordinates  with `Projection`'s [toPixels(GeoPoint, Point)](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection.html#toPixels(com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20android.graphics.Point)) method and then just draw to the passed in [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) using normal Android 2D drawing methods.

That's the basics... if you need anything else, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, sample coordinates and its usages.

```
//...setting map and starting 

ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new LatLng(41.020244, 29.045663));
list.add(new LatLng(41.019904, 29.045448));
list.add(new LatLng(41.019451, 29.044397));
list.add(new LatLng(41.019710, 29.043474));

PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions()
    .width(5)
    .color(Color.BLUE)
    .geodesic(true);

for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
    LatLng point = list.get(z);
    options.add(point);
}

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(41.020811, 29.046113))
    .zoom(15)
    .build();

mGoogleMap.addPolyline(options);
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```