# clicking in ballon in mapview should start another activity

Tags: android, google-maps

i created mapview in my application,and also markers inside the mapview which takes values from my json parsing and displayed it in the ballon popup .. again i need to start an activity when clicking in the baloon image i should start a new activity.. please help me to find a solution.. This is my BallonItemizedOverlayclass

```
package com.smartmedia.salonaudi.map;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import com.smartmedia.salonaudi.R;

public abstract class BalloonItemizedOverlay<Item extends OverlayItem> extends
        ItemizedOverlay<Item> {

    private MapView mapView;
    private BalloonOverlayView<Item> balloonView;
    private View clickRegion;
    private int viewOffset;
     private Context mContext;
      private Activity mActivity;
      private boolean mCheckIn;
    final MapController mc;

    /**
     * Create a new BalloonItemizedOverlay
     * 
     * @param defaultMarker
     *            - A bounded Drawable to be drawn on the map for each item in
     *            the overlay.
     * @param mapView
     *            - The view upon which the overlay items are to be drawn.
     */
    public BalloonItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(defaultMarker);
        this.mapView = mapView;
        mContext = mapView.getContext();
        viewOffset = 0;
        mc = mapView.getController();
    }

    /**
     * Set the horizontal distance between the marker and the bottom of the
     * information balloon. The default is 0 which works well for center bounded
     * markers. If your marker is center-bottom bounded, call this before adding
     * overlay items to ensure the balloon hovers exactly above the marker.
     * 
     * @param pixels
     *            - The padding between the center point and the bottom of the
     *            information balloon.
     */
    public void setBalloonBottomOffset(int pixels) {
        viewOffset = pixels;
    }

    public int getBalloonBottomOffset() {
        return viewOffset;
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to handle a "tap" on a balloon. By default, does
     * nothing and returns false.
     * 
     * @param index
     *            - The index of the item whose balloon is tapped.
     * @return true if you handled the tap, otherwise false.
     */
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index) {

        return true;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay#onTap(int)
     */
    @Override
    protected final boolean onTap(int index) {

        boolean isRecycled;
        final int thisIndex;
        GeoPoint point;

        thisIndex = index;
        point = createItem(index).getPoint();

        if (balloonView == null) {
            balloonView = createBalloonOverlayView();
            clickRegion = (View) balloonView
                    .findViewById(R.id.balloon_inner_layout);
            isRecycled = false;
        } else {
            isRecycled = true;
        }

        balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        if (mapOverlays.size() > 1) {
            hideOtherBalloons(mapOverlays);
        }

        balloonView.setData(createItem(index));


        MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point,
                MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;

        setBalloonTouchListener(thisIndex);

        balloonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (isRecycled) {
            balloonView.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {
            mapView.addView(balloonView, params);
        }

        mc.animateTo(point);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the balloon view. Override to create a sub-classed view that can
     * populate additional sub-views.
     */
    protected BalloonOverlayView<Item> createBalloonOverlayView() {
        return new BalloonOverlayView<Item>(getMapView().getContext(),
                getBalloonBottomOffset());
    }

    /**
     * Expose map view to subclasses. Helps with creation of balloon views.
     */
    protected MapView getMapView() {
        return mapView;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the visibility of this overlay's balloon view to GONE.
     */
    protected void hideBalloon() {
        if (balloonView != null) {
            balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hides the balloon view for any other BalloonItemizedOverlay instances
     * that might be present on the MapView.
     * 
     * @param overlays
     *            - list of overlays (including this) on the MapView.
     */
    private void hideOtherBalloons(List<Overlay> overlays) {

        for (Overlay overlay : overlays) {
            if (overlay instanceof BalloonItemizedOverlay<?> && overlay != this) {
                ((BalloonItemizedOverlay<?>) overlay).hideBalloon();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the onTouchListener for the balloon being displayed, calling the
     * overridden onBalloonTap if implemented.
     * 
     * @param thisIndex
     *            - The index of the item whose balloon is tapped.
     */
    private void setBalloonTouchListener(final int thisIndex) {

        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Method m = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("onBalloonTap",
                    int.class);

            clickRegion.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    View l = ((View) v.getParent())
                            .findViewById(R.id.balloon_main_layout);
                    Drawable d = l.getBackground();

                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        int[] states = { android.R.attr.state_pressed };
                        if (d.setState(states)) {
                            d.invalidateSelf();
                        }
                        return true;
                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        int newStates[] = {};
                        if (d.setState(newStates)) {
                            d.invalidateSelf();
                        }
                        // call overridden method
                        onBalloonTap(thisIndex);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            });

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("BalloonItemizedOverlay",
                    "setBalloonTouchListener reflection SecurityException");
            return;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // method not overridden - do nothing
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you should start your activity inside onBalloonTap() method. So what the problem you are getting ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps)

Answer (score 2):

```
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(this,
                    secondactivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(myintent);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: the class does not extends an activity then how we will add startActivity

Comment: add this class in your main activity as a inner class its works for me yar.........

Comment: @SamirMangroliya how to title of ballon tap

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context c;

    private int overlayIndex;
    private OnBalloonTapListener listener;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(defaultMarker, mapView);
        c = mapView.getContext();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        m_overlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return m_overlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return m_overlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index) {
        if (listener!=null){
            listener.onBalloonTap(overlayIndex);            
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setOnBallonTapListener(int overlayIndex, OnBalloonTapListener listener){
        this.overlayIndex = overlayIndex;
        this.listener = listener;       
    }   

    public interface OnBalloonTapListener{

        public void onBalloonTap(int balloonIndex);

    }

}
```

This is my custom overlay for listen tap on ballon. And I used it like this:

```
CustomItemizedOverlay overlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(marker, mapView);
        overlay.setOnBallonTapListener(overlayIndex, new OnBalloonTapListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBalloonTap(int balloonIndex) {
                //TODO something
            }
        });
```

It works for me very fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
GeoPoint adrpoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Lat() *1E6) , (int) (Lon() *1E6));
OverlayItem adroverlayitem = new OverlayItem(adrpoint, Title, Message);
final MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlayFind = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
itemizedOverlayFind.addOverlay(adroverlayitem);
itemizedOverlayFind.setOnBallonTapListener(itemizedOverlayFind.size()-1, new OnBalloonTapListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBalloonTap(int balloonIndex) {
        String msg = itemizedOverlayFind.getItem(balloonIndex).getSnippet();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg + ",Lat: " + itemizedOverlayFind.getItem(balloonIndex).getPoint().getLatitudeE6() + ", Lon: " + itemizedOverlayFind.getItem(balloonIndex).getPoint().getLongitudeE6(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //TODO something
    }
});
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlayFind);
itemizedOverlayFind.onTap(itemizedOverlayFind.size()-1);
mc.animateTo(adrpoint);
mc.setCenter(adrpoint);
```