# Find Nearest location from your current location & display that locations in list view & then on Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location-based-service

I am developing one application in which I am having database of the places with me as a addresses in form of String. Using Geocoders I am getting the Lat/Long of the same. I also done with my current location. Now from that current location I wish to get near by 4-5 places from my database. Another thing about this is that first i wish to display the nearest 4-5 location's addresses in ListView and if you clicked on any of it then it will display the map with distance of your current location to the destination and path of it.

I got the idea of this application from already developed application famously known as "Places" in android market.

Please kindly help me out in this I am very close to my application but stuck with some small things.

Thank You
Keyur

Answer (score 2):

Use [Location.distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) to get a list of distances from the current location and all the locations in the database.

Sort the result and choose the top 5 with the least distance from the current position. Get the addresses and pass this list in an String array in extras to a new list activity

> Because what i wish to do is that 5best nearest location which i get from distance.To()

Once you get these locations, You can send it in a String of the format

String topFive = "lat1,lon1 lat2,lon2 lat3,lon3 ..."

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TOP_FIVE_LOCATIONS", topFive );
startActivity(intent)
```

In the `onCreate()` of `YourListActivity.java`

```
String topFive = getIntent().getStringExtra("TOP_FIVE_LOCATIONS");
```

Now split this string using `String.split(" ")` and you will have an String [] of locations. Split again with "," and parse the lat, lon using `Double.parseDouble()`

You need to learn about `ListView`s next, I'll [direct you to a tutorial for this.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Once you have created your `ListView`, to set the lat, lon data in an adapter, the `ListView` will render the data in this adapter.

> method that will be displayed in well formed in list and if you click on the list

Use the `setOnItemClickListener()` to get item click events
You launch the next activity with the String coordinates, like before. This is a MapView.

> then it will display the map of that selected item and distance from your current location to that selected plus the path.

See [this to learn how to draw a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps) on the MapView.

Take baby steps since you are quite new to this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. But do you have any idea about ListView in Android? Because what i wish to do is that 5best nearest location which i get from distance.To() method that will be displayed in well formed in list and if you click on the list then it will display the map of that selected item and distance from your current location to that selected plus the path. If you have any idea about it please help me.

Comment: Ohhh.. Thank you so much buddy. You give me everything.. Ya i am doing one thing at a time and then integrate all of them in best optimized way. By the way thanks for your valuable time and sharing knowledge.

Comment: No problem, on StackOverflow we say thanks by upvoting or accepting the answer.

Comment: Hi Scorpion, Did you solved it? Basically i am also trying to do this.

Comment: Reno, can we email or chat? Im working on this for a glass app. I need to sort and get the top 5 locations and then draw lines on a map and make 5 cards for the glass timeline.