# Can we call MapView Inside an layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps

one of the the blogger has given an wonderful idea of calling MapView class inside an application.

[turn by turn directions in MapView](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/06/how-to-show-turn-by-turn-directions-on.html)

the code is

```
showDirections.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

`public void onClick(final View view) {
          final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,

          Uri.parse(
                   "http://maps.google.com/maps?" +
                   "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" +
                   "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355"));`

```
            intent.setClassName(
             "com.google.android.apps.maps",
             "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
      startActivity(intent);
```

}
});

Is it possible to attach this Mapview to a layout, so that it opens with in the layout of our application. As this method opens outside our layout and application. I am looking to fix this MapView to a layout.Any code examples.Looking forward to your reply.thanks

Comment: the above code has nothing to do with mapview , it opens google map app in ur device with an intent , please get ur basics right and do some research,

Answer (score 0):

I am writing answer to my own question and got help from other StackOverflow users.

This is full source code to draw direction path from source latitude and longitude to destination latitude and longitude. 
So anyone who is accessing his latitude and longitude through his gps can get the direction from his gps device to the destination coordinates.

StackOverflow had an answer and I have changed to latitude and longitude rather than source and destination places.

[stack overflow link for route path between source and destination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8926217/791169)

Thanks to above answers we could make such a change and get path direction.

```
public class DrawMapActivity extends MapActivity {
     MapView myMapView = null;
     MapController myMC = null;
     GeoPoint geoPoint = null;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      myMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

      geoPoint = null;
      myMapView.setSatellite(false);
      double fromLat = 12.303534;
      double fromLong = 76.64611;
      double toLat = 12.9715987;
      double toLong = 77.5945627;

      String sourceLat = Double.toString(fromLat);
      String sourceLong = Double.toString(fromLong);
      String destinationLat = Double.toString(toLat);
      String destinationLong = Double.toString(toLong);

      String pairs[] = getDirectionData(sourceLat,sourceLong, destinationLat, destinationLong );
      String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(",");

      // STARTING POINT
      GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6), (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));

      myMC = myMapView.getController();
      geoPoint = startGP;
      myMC.setCenter(geoPoint);
      myMC.setZoom(10);
      myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(startGP, startGP));

      // NAVIGATE THE PATH

      GeoPoint gp1;
      GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;

      for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++) {
       lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
       gp1 = gp2;
       // watch out! For GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude

       gp2 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6),(int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
       myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(gp1, gp2));
       Log.d("xxx", "pair:" + pairs[i]);
      }

      // END POINT
      myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(gp2, gp2));

      myMapView.getController().animateTo(startGP);
      myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);

     }

     @Override
     protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
     }

     private String[] getDirectionData(String sourceLat, String sourceLong, String destinationLat, String destinationLong) {


      String urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&" +"saddr="+sourceLat+","+sourceLong+"&daddr="+destinationLat+","+destinationLong + "&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml";
      Log.d("URL", urlString);
      Document doc = null;
      HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
      URL url = null;
      String pathConent = "";

      try {

       url = new URL(urlString.toString());
       urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
       urlConnection.connect();
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
       doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

      } catch (Exception e) {
      }

      NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString");
      for (int s = 0; s < nl.getLength(); s++) {
       Node rootNode = nl.item(s);
       NodeList configItems = rootNode.getChildNodes();
       for (int x = 0; x < configItems.getLength(); x++) {
        Node lineStringNode = configItems.item(x);
        NodeList path = lineStringNode.getChildNodes();
        pathConent = path.item(0).getNodeValue();
       }
      }
      String[] tempContent = pathConent.split(" ");
      return tempContent;
     }

    }


    //*****************************************************************************



     class DirectionPathOverlay extends Overlay {

        private GeoPoint gp1;
        private GeoPoint gp2;

        public DirectionPathOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2) {
            this.gp1 = gp1;
            this.gp2 = gp2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
                long when) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
            if (shadow == false) {

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                Point point = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Point point2 = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
                canvas.drawLine((float) point.x, (float) point.y, (float) point2.x,(float) point2.y, paint);
            }
            return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps for other Stack Overflow users