# Android: Draw direction in google map

Tags: android, gps, maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps)

Show  direction in google map from my current location to a restauarnt location ,Please help me with some examples

Comment: Please refer [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps