# How to draw an area (circle/polygon) on a mapview in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

How can i draw an area, like a circle or a polygon on the mapview with drag on the screen??, i searched for this question and found solutions only to draw lines between projections, but not this.

Moreover i must be able to get the area details after user done with drawing the area, like:

zoom level, center point lat and lng, radius/area

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps

Comment: yeah, exactly that is what i mentioned in my question....the question you posted tells how to draw lines between 2 or more Geo points :(

Comment: You can use canvas.drawCircle() for that purpose.

Comment: yeah thats for drawing...but this must be done after the user draws(or drags) his finger on the mapview....so how can i get the structure (what the user has drawn)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to Override `dispatchTouchEvent()`.  MapView's don't have `onTouchListener()`, so by using `dispatchTouchEvent()` you can intercept touches on the mapView, and then use those touches to draw a circle on the map.

As for the zoom level, use `mapView.getZoomLevel()` and for center use `mapView.getMapCenter()`.  Good luck!