# Drawing a path between points

Tags: java, android, google-maps, path, android-maps

I am working in Google Maps. I want to create a Path between 5 to 6 nodes, I mean just drawing a line between points.

The following class is an inner class for drawing:

```
class MyOverlay extends Overlay{
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

        Paint  mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(37423157, -122085008);
        GeoPoint gP3 = new GeoPoint(20000000 , -50000000) ; 
        GeoPoint[] G = new GeoPoint[3] ;
        G[1] = gP1 ; 
        G[2] = gP2 ; 
        G[3] = gP3 ; 
        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();
        Point p3 = new Point () ; 
        Path path = new Path();

        projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
        projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);
        projection.toPixels(gP3, p3) ; 
        //path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        //path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
        //path.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y) ;       
        //canvas.drawLines(pts , mPaint) ; 
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }
}
```

These two lines of code are the code from the `onCreate()` method in the outer class:

```
 projection = mapView.getProjection();

 mapOverlays.add(new MyOverlay());
```

Comment: You should add the points you have to the path which you are not doing currently.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct - the problem is you are not adding a `Point` to your `Path`.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184239/1345119) answer for something exactly similar to what you're doing.  Also, `draw()` is executed EVERY time the map needs to redraw the route, which is basically anytime the map moves.I have an app where I draw a route on the `MapView` and let me tell you, if your route gets long your map can get laggy.  So I would put your `Paint` stuff inside your class's constructor, so you're not creating a new object every time the route is redrawn.  Also, if you're planning to draw multiple points, I would use a `for` loop similar to this:

```
Path path = new Path();
for(GeoPoint g : arrayOfGeoPoints) {
            Point next = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(g, next);
            path.lineTo(next.x, next.y);
            path.moveTo(next.x, next.y);
        }
canvas.drawPath(path, myPaint);
```

It's simple, but can iterate through many points quickly and efficiently.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GeoPoint or MapView, so you may have other problems, but I can point out the obvious:

You've commented out the lines where you generate the Path, so you're drawing an empty Path.  If you uncomment the three lines starting with `path.` (but leave `canvas.drawLines(...)` commented), you *should* have a line from `p2` to `p1` and another one from `p1` to `p3`, assuming there isn't anything else wrong.