# plotting a route on Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps)

How would I use Google Maps API to plot a route? E.g to have a bunch of way points loaded onto the map (I currently have this) and draw a line from each of them showing the user a route they could take to see all of them? How would I then load this up when the user see's the map?

Comment: [this](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/map-api-in-android.html) may help you

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps) out, this question has been asked many times.  Basically, in `onDraw()` of your `Overlay` class you need to loop through your waypoints, building a `Path`.  Then at the end you draw the path on your map.  If that's confusing, just read the link :D