# KMZ vector file over Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, kmz

I have a KMZ vector file which works fine on my Google Earth application, but i want to overlay this on my phone (android) through Google maps.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

A KMZ file is simply an archived structure, containing a main KML file and zero or more supporting files.  I'm assuming you want the KML data?  That's what represents the "route"-like content of the KMZ.
   As far as displaying a KML file goes, it's been done before - check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723) previous SO question - it involves parsing the KML with a SAX parser (or other compatible parsing class) and piecing it into a path.  Once you have a list of coordinates, you can create a custom `Overlay` class, which could take in a coordinate list as an argument.  Then, on the `onDraw()` method of the `Overlay` class you simply draw a path representing the list of coordinates.  For more information on drawing routes, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps) out.

If that's not what you're looking for, drop a comment and I'll see what I can do!