# code example - google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I spent a lot of time to find a working example of drawing a path between 2 points in google map.

I finally find one but it isn't draw the path.

can someone help me understand why (or to give me another code example)?
this is the code:

https://github.com/frogermcs/RoutePathExample

Thank you.

Comment: See this previous post, it looks like the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

this link explains how to do it more clearly 
http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html
Are you aware of google earth kml ? 
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut
I used it once to plot route from 1 point to another on google map. once you parse it you can plot these points as 
`mapView.getProjection().toPixels(start, screenPts);`
`//---add the marker---`
`Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pin);`
`canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y, null);`
`Point screenPts2 = new Point();`
`mapView.getProjection().toPixels(end, screenPts2);`

`//---add the marker---`
`Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pin);// pin is a resource you have to add`
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, screenPts2.x, screenPts2.y, null);