# Draw path on google map during Driving/Walking

Tags: android, google-maps, path, routes

I am working on the application that require the draw the path on the google map. Here Starting point is the `current location`(latitude and langitude) of the user and when user change the place`(walking/Driving)` then as per the moving position get the user's current location(latitude and langitude) and draw the path on the google map as per the user's location.

I able to draw path between fix point.For that I am refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184239/1263679).

Thanks.

Comment: Try this [tut](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/map-api-in-android.html)

Comment: check this open source project - https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/

Comment: mytracks has been removed!! Is there any other way out?

Comment: I found this link for the open source project refered from KPBird i needed this thing so i found it here : https://github.com/barbeau/mytracks

Answer (score 2):

Use the Android Location API an example: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

and when you get your position, send the coordinates to google maps with an overlay for example.

Comment: Your example doesn't really answer the question.