# Android GetDirections

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, monodevelop, directions

I am using MonoDevelop for Android with Google Maps.

If I have two sets of Longitude/Latitude points, what is the best way to show the directions between these two points on a map?

Is there some sample code I can have a look at? Should I load a webpage that traces this route?

I just would like the easiest way to show directions that can be implemented into a Google Maps application that I am making for Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Google web API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests) to find Direction. It return a JSON
   contain results.
2. Then parsing them using [google http java client](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON). It return a
   list of lat/long points for you
3. Finally, draw those points into your maps. You can see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184239/1821326)