# how i draw path on google map when user move with device as user move draw the paths on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application in this application i want to draw a path on Google maps

When user moves with his device path is draw on map i don't want to draw path between two points

I want that every time when location is update path is drawn on map

If anyone know please help me 
Thanks

Comment: **Source:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps
hope it helps

Comment: You need to look at Polyline overlays and the LocationManager

Answer (score 1):

Each and everytime when you get new Latitude and Longitude, just call one user defined method, like, `drawTrack()`. But before that whatever value you got first time, just store that value in like in `previous_lat` and `previous_long` variable. Then, when you got lat-long second time that means your source lat-long is `previous_lat` and `previous_long` and latest one is which you have got currently. Then give that 4 vaues to `drawTrack()` method.

Inside `DrawTrack()` method,

```
googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(YOUR PREVIOUS LATITUDE VALUE), Double.parseDouble(YOUR PREVIOUS LONGITUDE VALUE), new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(YOUR LATEST LATITUDE VALUE), Double.parseDouble(YOUR LATEST LONGITUDE VALUE).width(5)     .color(getResources().getColor(R.color.BLACK)).geodesic(true));
```

Comment: its not working i written this code private void drawTrack(double new_lat, double new_long,
   double previous_lat, double previous_long) {
  PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
  options.add(new LatLng(previous_lat, previous_long));
  options.add(new LatLng(new_lat, new_long));
  options.width(15);
  options.color(Color.RED);
  mMap.addPolyline(options);
 }

Comment: @Mahtab ya then its must be work, check you have some other mistakes, because this code working prefect with me.

Comment: public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

  String msg = "Location:" + location.getLatitude() + ","
    + location.getLongitude();
  Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  double new_lat = location.getLatitude();
  double new_long = location.getLongitude();
  double previous_lat = new_lat;
  double previous_long = new_long;
  drawTrack(new_lat, new_long, previous_lat, previous_long);
 }

Comment: this is my on location changed method please see if any mistake tell me i am ne in android

Comment: odedraram28@gmail.com