# How to draw a tracking line between two coordinates

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am developing a tracking app that I will get the coordinates from an api.
I want to draw lines between the coordinates. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is well defined in the [android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) developers;

```
GoogleMap map;
// ... get a map.
// Add a thin red line from London to New York.
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
    .width(5)
    .color(Color.RED));
```

And, see [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps)