# Drawing lines between to points on a map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have two markers on a map. The code is found on [The developer site here.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) What I want to do is draw a line in between the two points. I have no idea what is to be done here. If I could get an example or tutorial site on this that would be great

-thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps

Comment: This question looks like it answers your question [Drawing line between two points][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937484/how-to-draw-line-on-map-view-given-coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question looks like it answers your question [Drawing line between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937484/how-to-draw-line-on-map-view-given-coordinates) since the markers are set using geopoints I assume this will work for you